# Getting error in VF page while parsing JSON and its returning as &quot;

Tags: apex, visualforce, json

My JSOn is -

```
{"InvalidData"{"userType":null,"status":"success","sessionToken":null,"name":null,"message":"success","mappingId":null,"emailId":null,"data":null,"code":1000}}
```

But VF is returning -

```
{&quot;InvalidData&quot;:{&quot;userType&quot;:null,&quot;status&quot;:&quot;success&quot;,&quot;sessionToken&quot;:null,&quot;name&quot;:null,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;success&quot;,&quot;mappingId&quot;:null,&quot;emailId&quot;:null,&quot;data&quot;:null,&quot;code&quot;:1000}}
```

So how to remove this `&quot` so that I can get the correct JSON as per my class.

My method is as below:

---

```
@RemoteAction
    global static String inValid(integer dataId,boolean contactValid, boolean productValid,
                                 boolean actionValid,String other){
      
       integer contact = 0;
       integer action = 0;
       integer product = 0;
       if(contactValid == true){
        contact = 1;                
       }
       if(productValid == true){
        product = 1;
       }
       if(actionValid == true){
        action = 1;
       }

       SalesAIRecommendations.Item response = new SalesAIRecommendations.Item();
        Recommendation__c recommendation = [SELECT Id,Recom_External_Id__c,Feedback__c FROM Recommendation__c where Recom_External_Id__c =: dataId];
                                            
        if(recommendation != null){
            system.debug('valid recommendation Id');
            recommendation.Feedback__c = other;
            update recommendation;
          
            Invalid_Recommendation__c invRec = new Invalid_Recommendation__c();
            invRec.Recommendation_ID__c = recommendation.Recom_External_Id__c;
            invRec.productChange__c = product;
            invRec.Next_Best_Action__c = action;
            invRec.contactId__c = contact;
            invRec.Others__c = recommendation.Feedback__c;
            insert invRec;
            response.status='success';
            response.code=1000;
            response.message = 'success';
          
            system.debug('{"InvalidData":' + JSON.serialize(response) + '}');
            return '{"InvalidData":' + JSON.serialize(response) + '}';
        }
        else{
            system.debug('invalid recommendation Id');   
            response.status='failure';
            response.code=1001;
            response.message = 'failure';
            system.debug('******:'  + '{"InvalidData":' + JSON.serialize(response) + '}');
            return '{"InvalidData":' + JSON.serialize(response) + '}';
                        
              }
    }
```

Comment: See the answer to e.g. [Why use JSON.serialize in @RemoteAction return statement](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13600/why-use-json-serialize-in-remoteaction-return-statement).

Comment: As this is remote action can you also share VF page code where you are making remote call?

Comment: @KeithC  i agree . No need to do  JSON,serialize , Directly you can return to VF page .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the class `SalesAIRecommendations.Item` serializes to JSON as you need it to, I think your problem is to just introduce one outer level of name/value. One way you can do that is:

```
public class Outer {
    public SalesAIRecommendations.Item InvalidData;
}

global static Outer inValid(...) {
    ...
       Outer o = new Outer();
       o.InvalidData = response;
       return o;
   ..
}
```

The framework automatically does the object graph to JSON string conversion for you (so no problems with extra escaping).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem. Its was coming because escape was true in VF code. It should be false like below. 
{escape: false}